# Как запустить скрипт git-http-backend через свой cgi скрипт без настройки apache?

Tags: git, http, apache2, cgi

Нужно запустить работу по-умному(не только скачивать проекты и пушить их) http протоколу через скрипт git-http-backend, я сделал как указано в документации через настройку веб сервера всё получилось, но нужно через свой cgi скрипт на lua

Comment: Что именно «нужно через свой cgi скрипт на lua»?

Comment: Клонировать отправлять репозитории, в общем действия гита, но нужно настроить через скрипт, а не apache

Comment: "cgi скрипт" подразумевает, что перед ним стоит веб сервер

Comment: Действия git'а выполняет не apache, а git-http-backend, который сам cgi-скрипт. Вы хотите между http-сервером и cgi-скриптом впихнуть ещё один cgi-скрипт? Зачем? или вы хотите git-http-backend заменить на свой cgi-скрипт? Без http-сервера cgi-скрипт всё равно работать не сможет.

Comment: Получается cgi-скрипт, который создаёт нужные настройки и запускает git-http-backend, а apach дать только права на выполнение cgi-скрипта